# Como usar un certificado ssl de ionos en mi EC2 de AWS con Nginx?

Tags: aws, nginx, ssl, ec2

He creado una instancia en EC2 en AWS para desplegar mi API, que luego usare en mi frontend. Todo esto salio correctamente y la API responde bien, sin embargo lo hace  a traves de http, quiero agregar los certificados ssl para usar https, sin embargo no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo a traves del uso de certificados externos a aws o que no use [certbot](/questions/tagged/certbot).

Lo que quisiera es poder descargar los archivos del certificado en mi equipo y luego usar la conexion al cliente ssh a traves de mi consola bash y configurar ahi los certificados.

Es la primera vez que despliego una aplicacion en una ec2 y bueno, este ultimo paso de agregar el ssl que me dieron me ha frenado bastante, agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.